# Unknown error creating MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two PHP documents. One that connects to my MySQL server and database (it will also create the database if it doesn't exist). This document is titled "db_connect.php". My next PHP document is titled "create.php" and it is designed to connect to a specific table within the database and create that table if it doesn't exist. There's also a javascript document involved in this which makes it so the user can type things and enter them into the table without the page being refreshed. I don't think you'll need this document and so I won't include it, but I thought you guys might find it helpful to know that this is for a message board.

Here's my db_connect.php file:

```
<?php
    $db = "my_db";
    //establish a connection with the server
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
    if(!$connection){
        exit("<p>Could not establish a connection :" . mysqli_connect_error() . "</p>");
    }
    //connect to the database
    $dbSelect = mysqli_select_db($connection, $db);
    if(!$dbSelect){
        // Create database
        $sql="CREATE DATABASE " . $db;
        if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
        } else {
          echo "<p>Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($connection) . "</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here's my create.php file:

```
<?php
//connect to the database
include('db_connect.php');
$table = 'NDI';
//update the table if the notes are posted
if(isset($_POST['notes'])){
    $notes=$_POST['notes'];
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $file = $_POST['file'];
    $file2 = $_FILES['file'];
    echo "<p>Hello $file $file2</p>";
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Check for file type
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-shockwave-flash")
        )
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 999000)){
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Check for errors
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }else{
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        //Set the upload
        ///////////////////////////////////////////

            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Check to see if file exists already
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (file_exists("../uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
                //echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                $_FILES["file"]["name"] =  rand(1, 1000).$_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //If not, move to the upload folder
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            $path = '../uploads/';
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $fn = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path.$fn);
            //move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            //"../uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: ../uploads/". $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $myImg =    "../uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
                //echo "\n $myImg";
        }
        //echo "<a href=../uploader/>Back</a>";
    }else{
        echo "Invalid file";
        //echo $_FILES["file"]["type"];
    }
    if(!$myImg){
        $myImg="../uploads/blank.png";
    }
    if(!$name){
        $name="anonymous";
    }
    $sql= "INSERT INTO `$table` SET `name` = '$name', `notes`='$notes', `img`='$myImg'";
    if (mysqli_query($sql)) {
        echo '<p>Entry added</p>';
        echo '<p><a href="index.php">' . $title . ' Home</a> </p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Error adding page: ' . mysqli_error() . '</p>';
    }
}
    //display results
$choices = mysqli_query("select * from " . $table);
if(!$choices){
    // Create table
    $sqlc="CREATE TABLE $table(`id` INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT, `img` VAR_CHAR(50), `name` VAR_CHAR(25), `notes` TEXT(500))";

    // Execute query
    if (mysqli_query($connection, $db, $sqlc)) {
    } else {
      echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($connection, $db);
    }
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($choices)){
    $img=$row['img'];
    $note=$row['notes'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    echo "<p class='note'><img src='$img'><span class='name'>$name: </span>$note</p>";
}
?>
```

The problem I'm running into is that the page echos the error: "Error creating table: " but it doesn't give me any of the error details that I told it to; so I really have no idea what to do. Any feedback you guys could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This statement `if (mysqli_query($connection, $db, $sqlc))` is basically telling SQL: connect to DB show the (word) `my_db` as as string (or try to pass as a parameter) then perform this query `$sqlc="CREATE TABLE $table...` doesn't seem to make sense. You may have meant to use `if(mysqli_query($connection, $sqlc))`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried changing `if (mysqli_query($connection, $db, $sqlc))` to `if (mysqli_query($connection, $sqlc))` and I still receive the same error.

Comment: Most likely because the table already exists (*or does it?*). You first have `$table = 'NDI';` (which I don't know if it exists or not), then you're querying with `$choices = mysqli_query("select * from " . $table);` then telling it to create the table `$sqlc="CREATE TABLE $table`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've checked with PHPMyAdmin and the table NDI doesn't exist in the database. The if statement it's within should return false if it did exist.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what the problem is. This `VAR_CHAR(50)` should be `VARCHAR(50)` you had an underscore. Plus `VAR_CHAR(25)` to `VARCHAR(25)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the tip! Now I have a new error: "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Comment: Add this `, PRIMARY KEY (id)` after `TEXT(500)` and put ticks around `id` SO doesn't render ticks well in comments.

Comment: So, how you making out?

Comment: Explain why this works and make it an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Also, would I have to put ticks around the `id` in `, PRIMARY KEY (id)` if I removed the ticks around the `id` in `id INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,`?

Comment: You will have to put ticks around `id` as noted above. As for "how it works", that I won't be able to give you a definite answer, only to say that I tried recreating your query in my PHPmyadmin and gave me an error, up until that I made it as a primary key.

Comment: Plus, if my addition worked with what you presently have, then leave it the way it is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay, well just write everything you told me as an answer and explain what you can. I'll mark that as correct and I'd be happy to vote up all of the comments you've made if you like. Thanks for all your help by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$sqlc="CREATE TABLE $table(`id` INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT, `img` VAR_CHAR(50), `name` VAR_CHAR(25), `notes` TEXT(500))";
```

to

```
$sqlc="CREATE TABLE $table(`id` INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT, `img` VARCHAR(50), `name` VARCHAR(25), `notes` TEXT(500), PRIMARY KEY (`id`))";
```

It's `VARCHAR` instead of `VAR_CHAR` plus you need to add a primary key to the auto_increment.

Quoted from http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqltables.php

> PRIMARY KEY is used as a unique identifier for the rows. Here we have made "id" the PRIMARY KEY for this table. This means that no two ids can be the same, or else we will run into trouble. This is why we made "id" an auto-incrementing counter in the previous line of code.

In other words, MySQL needs a column to uniquely identify a row.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong about this, but try leaving out the $db variable when calling mysqli_query and mysqli_error

```
 if (mysqli_query($connection, $sqlc)) {
```

...

```
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($connection);
```

Does that help?

Comment: [`As I said`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485676/unknown-error-creating-mysql-table-with-php#comment36012426_23485676)

Comment: This just makes me receive the error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VAR_CHAR(50), `name` VAR_CHAR(25), `notes` TEXT(500))' at line 1".

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the create *SQL* order including the database name
like this:

```
create table databasename.yourTable(etc table syntax)
```

Comment: Hi user, I appreciate your answer but at the same time I think you should be less concise (take it as a suggestion for your further answers). By the way the main problem on this question was that the mysqli_* function calls missed the connection parameter. Your solution is a bit out of scope. As far it will not produce harm would not solve the problem too  (and it will be prone to downvote for this very reason).